# How to shuffle array of implicit pairs?

Tags: python, arrays, shuffle

I am trying to do shuffling of pairs in an array of images, and it is a little bit tricky for me.

Example:
I have 20 sequences of images, each containing 1000 frames .. they are saved in an array .. so let's assume, the array looks like that

```
[[1_1],[1_2],[1_3],[1_4],[1_5],[1_6],[2_1],[2_2],[2_3],[2_4],[2_5],[2_6],[3_1],[3_2],[3_3],[3_4],[3_5],[3_6]]
```

And so on, this is just a minimal example of 3 sequences, each having 6 frames .. but what I want to achieve in the end, of shuffling of sequential frames, so something like that

```
[[1_4],[1_5],[2_3],[2_4],[3_5],[3_6],[1_3],[1_4],[1_1],[1_2],[3_2],[3_3],[1_2],[1_3],[3_3],[3_4],[2_1],[2_2] ....]
```

So something like this simply .. So I want to produce a shuffle, but instead of single elements, it will be each element along with the follwoing one, i.e. I want to shuffle pairs.

Is there a way to do so ?

Comment: `[1_1]` is confusing, do you mean `['1_1']`?

Comment: I am just referring to the first image in the first sequence .. nothing more -- actually `1_1` is a 3D array (RGB image)

Comment: Would an answer which works on `['1_1']` be helpful?

Comment: can you show me an example of the answer you mean ?

Comment: I take that as a "Yes".

Comment: You might improve the question by showing what you tried (e.g. simply `random.shuffle(L)`) and explaining what is wrong about the result (e.g. that the relation of one entry with the first following one is lost). That way it might harvest an upvote or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am working on a cleaner nested list (mistrusting the `[1_1]`):

```
L = [['1_1'],['1_2'],['1_3'],['1_4'],['1_5'],['1_6'],['2_1'],['2_2'],['2_3'],['2_4'],['2_5'],['2_6'],['3_1'],['3_2'],['3_3'],['3_4'],['3_5'],['3_6']]
```

Then I create a nested list, i.e. a list of pairs, with a comprehension:

```
S=[[L[z*2+y] for y in range(2)] for z in range(len(L)//2)] # version 1
S=[[L[z+y] for y in range(2)] for z in range(len(L)-1)]    # version 2
S
```

Note that there are length/2 non-overlapping pairs,
but N-1 overlapping pairs (one pair for each entry, except the last).

Note that in all outputs below I have manually added newlines for readability
and clarity purposes.

Output at this point is:

Version 1, non-overlapping pairs:

```
[[['1_1'], ['1_2']], 
 [['1_3'], ['1_4']],
 [['1_5'], ['1_6']], 
 [['2_1'], ['2_2']],
 [['2_3'], ['2_4']],
 [['2_5'], ['2_6']],
 [['3_1'], ['3_2']],
 [['3_3'], ['3_4']],
 [['3_5'], ['3_6']]]
```

Version 2, overlapping pairs:

```
[[['1_1'], ['1_2']],
 [['1_2'], ['1_3']],
 [['1_3'], ['1_4']],
 [['1_4'], ['1_5']],
 [['1_5'], ['1_6']],
 [['1_6'], ['2_1']],
 [['2_1'], ['2_2']],
 [['2_2'], ['2_3']],
 [['2_3'], ['2_4']],
 [['2_4'], ['2_5']],
 [['2_5'], ['2_6']],
 [['2_6'], ['3_1']],
 [['3_1'], ['3_2']],
 [['3_2'], ['3_3']],
 [['3_3'], ['3_4']],
 [['3_4'], ['3_5']],
 [['3_5'], ['3_6']]]
```

Then shuffle S, which will only shuffle the pairs within S, not within the pairs, that is the point of making the list of pairs first.

```
import random
random.shuffle(S)
S
```

Output at this point, still nested of course:

Non-overlapping random pairs:

```
[[['3_3'], ['3_4']],
 [['3_1'], ['3_2']],
 [['2_3'], ['2_4']],
 [['3_5'], ['3_6']],
 [['1_1'], ['1_2']],
 [['1_3'], ['1_4']],
 [['2_1'], ['2_2']],
 [['1_5'], ['1_6']],
 [['2_5'], ['2_6']]]
```

Output overlapping random pairs:

```
[[['1_2'], ['1_3']],
 [['2_1'], ['2_2']],
 [['2_4'], ['2_5']],
 [['2_2'], ['2_3']],
 [['1_3'], ['1_4']],
 [['3_4'], ['3_5']],
 [['3_3'], ['3_4']],
 [['3_2'], ['3_3']],
 [['1_6'], ['2_1']],
 [['2_5'], ['2_6']],
 [['2_6'], ['3_1']],
 [['1_4'], ['1_5']],
 [['1_1'], ['1_2']],
 [['2_3'], ['2_4']],
 [['1_5'], ['1_6']],
 [['3_1'], ['3_2']],
 [['3_5'], ['3_6']]]
```

Maybe you can use that for the rest of the project.
If not dissolve the pairs

```
L2=[]
for x in S:
  for y in x:
    L2.append(y)
print(L2)
```

Output dissolved non-overlapping pairs:

```
[['3_3'], ['3_4'], ['3_1'], ['3_2'], ['2_3'], ['2_4'],
 ['3_5'], ['3_6'], ['1_1'], ['1_2'], ['1_3'], ['1_4'],
 ['2_1'], ['2_2'], ['1_5'], ['1_6'], ['2_5'], ['2_6']]
```

Output dissolved overlapping pairs:

```
[['1_2'], ['1_3'], ['2_1'], ['2_2'], ['2_4'], ['2_5'],
 ['2_2'], ['2_3'], ['1_3'], ['1_4'], ['3_4'], ['3_5'],
 ['3_3'], ['3_4'], ['3_2'], ['3_3'], ['1_6'], ['2_1'],
 ['2_5'], ['2_6'], ['2_6'], ['3_1'], ['1_4'], ['1_5'],
 ['1_1'], ['1_2'], ['2_3'], ['2_4'], ['1_5'], ['1_6'],
 ['3_1'], ['3_2'], ['3_5'], ['3_6']]
```

Comment: but this is not what I want exactly, here you shuffled the whole sequences
so if I have 6 sequences from 1-6 arranged, then what you are doing will do them like that 1,3,6,4,5 for example

what I want is that I shuffle the frames inside the image sequences themselves, as shown in my example above

Comment: No, it only shuffles whole 6groups, not within, you can see that in the outputs I have provided.

Comment: yes exactly, this is what I am saying .. it is not what I want

Comment: You simply want to shuffle the list, without keeping the sixgroups? What is so special about that?

Comment: Or do you mean that you want to shuffle keeping pairs together?

Comment: what I want to have, is something like this `[[1_4],[1_5],[2_3],[2_4],[3_5],[3_6],[1_3],[1_4],[1_1],[1_2],[3_2],[3_3],[1_2],[1_3],[3_3],[3_4],[2_1],[2_2] ....]` so pairs shuffling, not single frame shuffling

Comment: I will try your answer now ..in the second step ? why do you have range of 9 ? because my real project is 20 sequences, each 1000 frames

Comment: Ok I tried, it is nearly achieving what I want but not completely. I'll try to elaborate. Firstly, instead of `for z in range(9)` I need maybe a general expression, dependent on the size of my list or something ... Secondly, this is correctly shuffling into pairs, but it is never repeated .. like in my example above, you can see that the expected output can be something like that `[[1_4],[1_5],[2_3],[2_4],[3_5],[3_6],[1_3],[1_4],[1_1],[1_2],[3_2],[3_3],[1_2],[1_3],[3_3],[3_4],[2_1],[2_2] ....]`, here you can notice that for example `[1,4]` is located once before `[1,5]` and once after `[1,3]`

Comment: Please try `S=[[L[z+y] for y in range(2)] for z in range(len(L)-1)]`.

Comment: I did edit to show both, overlapping and non-overlapping pairs.

Answer (score 0):

We will need a few imports to simplify things:

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import groupby
import operator
import random
```

Assuming you have a list like:

```
ar = [['1_1'],['1_2'],['1_3'],['1_4'],['1_5'],['1_6'],['2_1'],['2_2'],['2_3'],['2_4'],['2_5'],['2_6'],['3_1'],['3_2'],['3_3'],['3_4'],['3_5'],['3_6']]
```

We can first group them up by image so that we only generate valid pairs:

```
groupedbyimage = [list(g[1]) for g in groupby(ar, lambda x: x[0][0])]
```

*The above lambda would have to be something else in your case in order to generate find the correct groups when not just comparing the first letter in the string in the nested lists.*

Next we can zip the image lists with themselves shifted by one:

```
groupedandpaired = [list(zip(x, x[1:])) for x in groupedbyimage]
```

We can now flatten the `groupedandpaired` list into a `pairlist`:

```
pairlist = reduce(operator.concat, groupedandpaired)
```

Now we can just shuffle the list of pairs and then flatten it again to get the desired result:

```
random.shuffle(pairlist)
result = list(reduce(operator.concat, pairlist))
```

And printing the result in the REPL we see something like:

```
>>> result
[['1_5'], ['1_6'], ['2_1'], ['2_2'], ['1_1'], ['1_2'], ['3_2'], 
 ['3_3'], ['2_2'], ['2_3'], ['3_5'], ['3_6'], ['3_1'], ['3_2'], 
 ['1_3'], ['1_4'], ['1_4'], ['1_5'], ['3_4'], ['3_5'], ['3_3'], 
 ['3_4'], ['2_5'], ['2_6'], ['2_3'], ['2_4'], ['1_2'], ['1_3'], 
 ['2_4'], ['2_5']]
```