# DataLoader - shuffle implicit pairs

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

Is there a way to handle the `DataLoader` as a list ? The idea is that I want to shuffle implicit pairs of images, without setting the shuffling into True

Basically, I have for example 10 scenes, each containing let's say 100 sequences, so they are represented inside the directory as

```
'1_1.png', '1_2.png', '1_3.png', '....., '2_1.png', '2_2.png', '2_3.png', ...., '3_1.png', '3_2.png', '3_3.png', ..., ...., '10_1.png', '10_2.png', '10_3.png', ...
```

I don't want complete shuffling of data, what I want simply is to shuffle but keeping pairs, so they are represented in the data loader as

`[ '1_3.png', '1_4.png', '2_2.png', '2_3.png', '10_1.png', '10_2.png', '1_2.png', '1_3.png', ...]`
and so on

Please have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980490/how-to-shuffle-array-of-implicit-pairs) which I have already asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) concerning shuffling array of implicit pairs, where you can understand what I mean

As an example:
if this is a list

```
L = [['1_1'],['1_2'],['1_3'],['1_4'],['1_5'],['1_6'],['2_1'],['2_2'],['2_3'],['2_4'],['2_5'],['2_6'],['3_1'],['3_2'],['3_3'],['3_4'],['3_5'],['3_6']]
```

then this is the output

```
[['1_2'], ['1_3'], ['2_1'], ['2_2'], ['2_4'], ['2_5'],
 ['2_2'], ['2_3'], ['1_3'], ['1_4'], ['3_4'], ['3_5'],
 ['3_3'], ['3_4'], ['3_2'], ['3_3'], ['1_6'], ['2_1'],
 ['2_5'], ['2_6'], ['2_6'], ['3_1'], ['1_4'], ['1_5'],
 ['1_1'], ['1_2'], ['2_3'], ['2_4'], ['1_5'], ['1_6'],
 ['3_1'], ['3_2'], ['3_5'], ['3_6']]
```

I want to achieve the same for a `DataLoader`

The main idea, is that I want to train my network on sequential frames, but it doesn't have to be the complete sequence, but at least I need each step, two sequences are there

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [`data.Sampler`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Sampler): instead of the completely radom default shuffle of `data.DataLoader`, you can provide your own "sampler" that sample examples from your `Dataset`.
Looking at the input parameters of [`data.DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader):

> **sampler** (`Sampler`, optional) – defines the strategy to draw samples
>   from the dataset. If specified, `shuffle` must be `False`.

I think a good starting point for is too look at the code of [`data.SubsetRandomSampler`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.SubsetRandomSampler).

Comment: `data.SubsetRandomSampler` takes given indices and gives out samples which lie in these indices, I don't see how this is related to what I want, can you please explain with an example, if possible ?

Comment: @MostafaHussein I think you should **implement** a `data.Sampler` of your own that fits your specific demands. I also think using `data.SubsetRandomSampler`'s code as a reference can help you implement your own sampler.